# How to call an instance method when using forEach()

Tags: java, foreach, lambda

I'm a Java newbie and I would like to call a member function for each key-value pair in a `Properties` object as follows:

```
public void addOption(String key, String value)
{
    // ...
}

public void foo()
{
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    // reads the property list from the input byte stream
    ...

    properties.forEach( (key, value) -> this.addOption(key, value));  // compiler error
    properties.forEach( (key, value) -> System.out.println("Key: " + key + ": Value: " + value));   // OK
}
```

The following compiler error is reported:

```
The method addOption(String, String) in the type Configuration is not applicable for the arguments (Object, Object)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What type is `key`?  show us the definition

Comment: It seems that your `key` and `value` are the `Object` type, so just type cast it and try.

Comment: @RossDrew I've added the definition. Keys and values are `String`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.util.Properties` extends `Hashtable<Object,Object>`.

Therefore you'll have to cast the key and value to `String` in order to call your method (assuming all the keys and values are actually `String`s) :

```
properties.forEach( (key, value) -> this.addOption((String) key, (String) value));
```

The alternative is to change the signature of your method to :

```
public void addOption(Object key, Object value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should cast `key` and `value` to `String`:

```
   properties.forEach( (key, value) -> this.addOption((String)key, (String) value));
```

And why don't you use `Map<String,String>` to gain advantages of `Generic`

Comment: Can you elaborate? My understanding is that the type Properties is not generic.